# Joining Sales within a Calendar Range - SQL

Tags: sql, qliksense

I have some SQL questions, if anyone could help!
I'm doing this through Qlik Sense:
I'm playing with some play data to see if I can create the following table and attribute an ID for each specific period.
E.g, I have sales data where I can see the quantities sold on each date, for example, 29/06/2020 in this.
This falls inside of period P01, however, how can I allocate the key of 'Period' when it falls within a specifed range.

E.g, any sale made between 29/06/2020 -> 19/07/2020 would have 'P01' as the period column and so on?
See below demo:
https://gyazo.com/a4776cdcff3bb7cb7c503b53ab43791f

Comment: People here are probably not going to click on a random link.  All relevant data should be in the question.  thanks

Comment: Hi OldProgrammer, unfortunately it's an excel document, and I cannot link a document attachment here. It's a gyazo link which is just a screenshot (I assume pretty credible).